# Firebase DB: Check if node has no children?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I find out if a Firebase DB node has no children? Seems the only way to get data is with listeners, and they only fire when something is added or removed. In other words, if there are no children, nothing will fire.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#hasChildren()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `addValueEventListener`, and in `onDataChange` you will have some way to check no children.
The `addValueEventListener` will work because arcoding this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

> This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again
>   every time the data, including children, changes

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // As cricket_007 we also can use hasChildren or getChildrenCount
        if(!snapshot.hasChildren()){
            // db has no children
        }

        // OR this way
        if(snapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0){
            // db has no children
        }

        // OR this way
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            // db has no children
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What if specific node will have too much children? This approach will be too expensive while executing.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the `child` is present in `Firebase` or not by using the `getChildrenCount()` or `exists()` method of `DataSnapshot`.

```
 searchFirebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Log.d("FIREBASE",String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
        String childrenCount = String.valueOf(datasnapshot.getChildrenCount());

       if(childrenCount != null){

          }else{

          //No childrens in Firebase Database
       }

//OR 

       if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){

          //No data   

         }


      }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }

    });
```

See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getChildrenCount()) for more info. I hope this helps you.