# On remove of last left child node, my respective firebase table gets deleted

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a scenario where I have firebase json db, in which I have a json object of agents. Here, if I delete the last left child node, then the table(node) agents gets removed as well.

How I can I restrict that this agents(parent node) doesnt get deleted even if I am deleting the last child left into it, or, How I can re-create the parent node(agents) after the removal of last left child node?

Below is what I am doing through code:

```
    FriendlyChat.prototype.signOut = function () {

      var userdetails = this.auth.currentUser;

      this.database.ref('agents').child(userdetails.displayName).remove();

      this.auth.signOut();
    };

FriendlyChat.prototype.onAuthStateChanged = function (user) {

  if (user) { // User is signed in!
    // Get profile pic and user's name from the Firebase user object.
    //console.log(user);
    var profilePicUrl = user.photoURL;
    var userEmail = user.email;
    var userName = user.displayName;
    this.agentsRef = this.database.ref('agents');
    var loginTime = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);


    this.agentsRef.child(userName).set({
      emailId: userEmail,
      login_time: loginTime,
      name: userName
    })

  } else { // User is signed out!
    // Hide user's profile and sign-out button.
// Something happens

  }
};
```

Firebase DB:

```
{
  "agents" : {
    "test test" : {
      "emailId" : "testrbcdemo@gmail.com",
      "login_time" : 7686887,
      "name" : "test test"
    }
  },
  "engagedUsers" : {
    "qwe" : {
      "agent_availability" : true,
      "conv_id" : "testrbcdemo_qwe",
      "emailId" : "qwe@gmail.com",
      "login_time" : 66565656,
      "name" : "qwe",
      "uid" : "adasfklsfjdskldgsgjgjkl"
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is normal behavior for Firebase since it is a node based system. The table gets regenerated when a new child is added. The reason Firebase does this is for you not to have empty tables (nodes).

The way Firebase works is by checking if the node already exists and recreates it if it does not. If it exists, a key value pair is added as a child of that node. This means that ultimately you need to end up with a key value pair, no matter how many nodes you have.

For example:

```
 - Customer
     - Address
         - AddressLine1: The Hive
         - AddressLine2: Southampton Ave
         - AddressLine3: New York
         - Country: USA
```

In the example above, the address node contains data separated in 4 children. If I remove AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3 and Country, the Address node is automatically removed since it has no children.

Once I add a new address to that Customer, the Address node is recreated.

Comment: Agreed and experienced to what you have mentioned, but I have scenario where I have listener which is specifically listening to agents  node, if it finds any then it does its rest of the process

Comment: It has to be like that in my model, that If I see some thing available there then I got to move the data to other table removing it from here..

Comment: Then you need to make a check when querying the address node to check if it has any children. You can use the `addValueEventListener`. Check this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write and this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154868/1116216